# The pigeonhole principle - $30$ pens in a drawer

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I need help with the following task. It needs to be solved using the pigeonhole principle.

> There are $10$ red, $8$ blue, $8$ purple and $4$ yellow pens in a drawer. We pick them out, one by one, in the dark. What is the least number of pens that we need to pull out if we want to ensure that we have

> $a$) at least $1$ pen of each color.

> $b$) at least $6$ blue pens.

I realize for example that if we want at lest $4$ pens of each color, we need to pull out at least $11$ ones, but I do not understand how to get one of each, or a specific number of a given color. I would solve this using statistics, but it has to be the principle.

Comment: Think in terms of worst case scenarios.  How many pens could you pull from the drawer before you finally obtain at least one pen of each color?

Comment: "I realize for example that if we want at least 4 pens of each color, we need to pull out at least 11 ones" does not look correct.  Did you mean "if we want pens with at least 2 colors, we need to pull out at least 11 pens"?

Comment: At most $27$ and $28$ respectively in the worst case.

Comment: Half-duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1612271/how-to-implement-the-generalized-pigeonhole-principle

Answer (score 0):

Think logically.
Since you are drawing pens in the dark, it is very much possible that you require the maximum possible number of draws, i.e.

For $1^{st}$ case:
You might start off with Red, then finish off all Reds, Blues and Purples, i.e. $10+8+8=26$ draws in the worst case. Now, only left with Yellow, just draw one.
So, **at most** you may need $27$ draws.
While, if **lucky** enough, you may grab $4$ different colors in just $4$ draws.
So, to be sure, you will need **at least** $27$ draws.

For $2^{nd}$ case:
Finish drawing all other colors, contributing to $10+8+4=22$ draws. Now, left with only Blues, just draw $6$, so **at most** $22+6=28$ draws in the worst-case.
Again, in the **rarest** case, you may need just $6$ draws; though its probability is quite less.
So, to be sure, you will need **at least** $28$ draws.

Try to convince yourself!